# Snowflake UDF in JavaScript does not calculate as expected

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to calculate the number of minutes a logged job has been running.
Each job has a start time and an end time.

In this particular case, the working hours are between 01:00 and 10:00, and only business days (weekends excluded)

In order to calculate this, I tried and made a JavaScript based UDF like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JobRuns(f datetime, t datetime)
RETURNS DOUBLE
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    // Based on the Calculation of Business Hours in JavaScript
    // https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/36985e/calculating-business-hours-in-javascript/
    
    function workingMinutesBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) {    
        // Store minutes worked    
        var minutesWorked = 0;    
    
        // Validate input    
        if (endDate < startDate) {    
            return 0;    
        }    
        
        // Loop from your Start to End dates (by hour)    
        var current = startDate;    
        
        // Define work range    
        var workHoursStart = 1;    
        var workHoursEnd = 10;    
        var includeWeekends = false;    
        
        // Loop while currentDate is less than end Date (by minutes)    
        while (current <= endDate) {    
            // Is the current time within a work day (and if it occurs on a weekend or not)     
            if (current.getHours() >= workHoursStart && current.getHours() <= workHoursEnd && (includeWeekends ? current.getDay() !== 0 && current.getDay() !== 6 : true)) {    
                minutesWorked++;    
            }    
        
            // Increment current time    
            current.setTime(current.getTime() + 1000 * 60);    
        }    
        
        // Return the number of minutes
        return minutesWorked;    
    }   
    return workingMinutesBetweenDates(F,T);
$$
;
```

But the result I am getting are in some cases rather off from what I had expected.

[image]

The JS logic is grabbed from here; https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/36985e/calculating-business-hours-in-javascript/ and when I look at the code, I cannot see any flaws, which might cause these discrepancies.

I am using these test data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "SLA_Test" (
    "DocumentID" VARCHAR(16777216),
    "From" TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    "To" TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    "ExpectedTime" INT
  );
  
  INSERT INTO "SLA_Test"
  VALUES
    ('ACD7EFC1-8D17-46E3-84DB-C08067466866','2021-03-03 07:12:34.567','2021-03-03 08:12:34.567',60),
    ('C41FB599-D1EC-4461-BBAF-1AFF67D2F3C2','2021-03-03 09:55:00.000','2021-03-04 01:05:00.000',10),
    ('B741C663-732B-4FD3-839D-E70330C58990','2021-03-03 09:55:00.000','2021-03-04 00:05:00.000',5),
    ('C5893C51-F5CE-40E4-85F7-775515BC3E3D','2021-03-03 19:55:00.000','2021-03-04 01:05:00.000',5),
    ('BAF4ED57-8184-4CDF-8875-DFDA6EAC2033','2021-03-03 09:55:00.000','2021-03-05 01:05:00.000',550),
    ('F325059E-E78F-4DCE-B675-CC1C59669B3C','2021-03-05 09:55:00.000','2021-03-08 01:05:00.000',10),
    ('F325059E-E78F-4DCE-B675-CC1C59669B3C','2021-03-05 09:55:00.000','2021-03-07 01:05:00.000',5);

SELECT "DocumentID","From","To",
    DATEDIFF(second, "From", "To") AS "TotalElapsedTimeSecond",
    DATEDIFF(second, "From", "To")/60 AS "TotalElapsedTimeMinut",
    "ExpectedTime",
    JobRuns("From","To") AS "ElapsedTimeMinut"
FROM "SLA_Test";
```

Any ideas why the UDF does not return the expected time?

Comment: Are all your ExpectedTime values in minutes? Can you explain why the ExpectedTime between '2021-03-03 09:55:00' and '2021-03-04 01:05:00' is 10 minutes (or, in fact, explain the calculation behind any of the ExpectedTime values you have given - apart from the first one)?

Comment: Working hours are between 01 & 10. So 09:55 will give you 5 minutes worktime that day.
01:05 is next day, and gives 5 more minutes of work time = total 10 minutes in that case.
Hope that clears it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can all be done in SQL,

```
with SLA_Test(DocumentID, FromTime, ToTime, ExpectedTime) AS (
  SELECT column1, column2::timestamp_ntz, column3::timestamp_ntz, column4 
  FROM
  VALUES
    ('ACD7EFC1-8D17-46E3-84DB-C08067466866','2021-03-03 07:12:34.567','2021-03-03 08:12:34.567',60),
    ('C41FB599-D1EC-4461-BBAF-1AFF67D2F3C2','2021-03-03 09:55:00.000','2021-03-04 01:05:00.000',10),
    ('B741C663-732B-4FD3-839D-E70330C58990','2021-03-03 09:55:00.000','2021-03-04 00:05:00.000',5),
    ('C5893C51-F5CE-40E4-85F7-775515BC3E3D','2021-03-03 19:55:00.000','2021-03-04 01:05:00.000',5),
    ('BAF4ED57-8184-4CDF-8875-DFDA6EAC2033','2021-03-03 09:55:00.000','2021-03-05 01:05:00.000',550),
    ('F325059E-E78F-4DCE-B675-CC1C59669B3C','2021-03-05 09:55:00.000','2021-03-08 01:05:00.000',10),
    ('F325059E-E78F-4DCE-B675-CC1C59669B3C','2021-03-05 09:55:00.000','2021-03-07 01:05:00.000',5)
), days as (
    SELECT row_number() over(order by seq8())-1 as num
    FROM table(GENERATOR(rowcount=>30))
), enriched as (
    SELECT *,
        datediff('day', s.fromtime, s.totime) as tot_days
  from SLA_Test AS s
), day_sliced AS (
  select s.*
      ,d.*
      ,date_trunc('day',fromtime) f_s
      ,dateadd('day', d.num, f_s) as clip_day
      ,dateadd('hour', 1, clip_day) as clip_start
      ,dateadd('hour', 10, clip_day) as clip_end
      ,dayofweekiso(clip_day) as dowi
      ,dowi >=1 AND dowi <= 5 as work_day
      ,least(greatest(s.fromtime, clip_start),clip_end) as slice_start
      ,greatest(least(s.totime, clip_end), clip_start) as slice_end
      ,DATEDIFF('second', slice_start, slice_end) as slice_sec
      ,DATEDIFF('minute', slice_start, slice_end) as slice_min
  from enriched AS s
  join days AS d on d.num <= s.tot_days
  qualify work_day = true
)
SELECT 
    DocumentID
    ,FromTime
    ,ToTime
    ,ExpectedTime
    ,round(sum(slice_sec)/60,0) as elasped_time_minutes
FROM day_sliced
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

which gives the results as noted in expected:

```
DOCUMENTID                              FROMTIME                TOTIME     EXPECTEDTIME ELASPED_TIME_MINUTES
ACD7EFC1-8D17-46E3-84DB-C08067466866    2021-03-03 07:12:34.567 2021-03-03 08:12:34.567 60  60
B741C663-732B-4FD3-839D-E70330C58990    2021-03-03 09:55:00.000 2021-03-04 00:05:00.000 5   5
BAF4ED57-8184-4CDF-8875-DFDA6EAC2033    2021-03-03 09:55:00.000 2021-03-05 01:05:00.000 550 550
C41FB599-D1EC-4461-BBAF-1AFF67D2F3C2    2021-03-03 09:55:00.000 2021-03-04 01:05:00.000 10  10
C5893C51-F5CE-40E4-85F7-775515BC3E3D    2021-03-03 19:55:00.000 2021-03-04 01:05:00.000 5   5
F325059E-E78F-4DCE-B675-CC1C59669B3C    2021-03-05 09:55:00.000 2021-03-07 01:05:00.000 5   5
F325059E-E78F-4DCE-B675-CC1C59669B3C    2021-03-05 09:55:00.000 2021-03-08 01:05:00.000 10  10
```

Comment: Thanks @simeon-pilgrim, this is amazing, and got me to take a deeper look into the power of CTE

Answer (score 2):

If you create a working hours table, you can run the following query:

```
select
  t.id
  , sum(datediff(‘second’, 
               -- calculate the max of the two start time
               (case when t.start <= 
                          w.working_day_start_timestamp
                     then w.working_day_start_timestamp
                     else t.start
                end),
               -- calculate the min of the two end times
               (case when t.end >= 
                          w.working_day_end_timestamp
                     then w.working_day_end_timestamp
                     else t.end 
                end)
               )) / 3600 -- convert to hourly
  as working_hour_diff
from 
  working_days_times w,
  cross join time_intervals t
where -- select all intersecting intervals
  (
   t.start <= w.working_day_end_timestamp
   and
   t.end >= w.working_day_start_timestamp
  )
and -- select only working days
  w.is_working_day
group by
  t.id
```

This article also goes into more detail about implementing this as a Javascript UDF: https://medium.com/dandy-engineering-blog/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-working-hours-between-two-timestamps-in-sql-b5696de66e51

Answer (score 1):

Did you test this outside of Snowflake?  I just created the following file and running `node /tmp/dates.js` produces this output which matches up with Snowflake

```
// Col1: function return, Col2: Expected
61 60
71 10
65 5
6 5
671 550
1271 10
671 5
```

```
function workingMinutesBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) {    
    // Store minutes worked    
    var minutesWorked = 0;    

    // Validate input    
    if (endDate < startDate) {    
        return 0;    
    }    
    
    // Loop from your Start to End dates (by hour)    
    var current = startDate;    
    
    // Define work range    
    var workHoursStart = 1;    
    var workHoursEnd = 10;    
    var includeWeekends = false;    
    
    // Loop while currentDate is less than end Date (by minutes)    
    while (current <= endDate) {    
        // Is the current time within a work day (and if it occurs on a weekend or not)     
        if (current.getHours() >= workHoursStart && current.getHours() <= workHoursEnd && (includeWeekends ? current.getDay() !== 0 && current.getDay() !== 6 : true)) {    
            minutesWorked++;    
        }    
    
        // Increment current time    
        current.setTime(current.getTime() + 1000 * 60);    
    }    
    
    // Return the number of minutes
    return minutesWorked;    
} 


console.log(workingMinutesBetweenDates((new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-03 07:12:34.567'))), (new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-03 08:12:34.567')))), 60);
console.log(workingMinutesBetweenDates((new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-03 09:55:00.000'))), (new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-04 01:05:00.000')))), 10);
console.log(workingMinutesBetweenDates((new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-03 09:55:00.000'))), (new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-04 00:05:00.000')))), 5);
console.log(workingMinutesBetweenDates((new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-03 19:55:00.000'))), (new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-04 01:05:00.000')))), 5);
console.log(workingMinutesBetweenDates((new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-03 09:55:00.000'))), (new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-05 01:05:00.000')))), 550);
console.log(workingMinutesBetweenDates((new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-05 09:55:00.000'))), (new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-08 01:05:00.000')))), 10);
console.log(workingMinutesBetweenDates((new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-05 09:55:00.000'))), (new Date(Date.parse('2021-03-07 01:05:00.000')))), 5);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I better get started in using node.js so I can debug javascript locally

Comment: You can also test Javascript right in a browser with the Web Inspector console if you don't want to bother with node.

Answer (score 1):

I've found at least 2 issues with the code, I think:

1. It will always over-count by at least 1. On the first loop round the WHILE statement the minutesWorked is incremented but at that point no time has actually been worked - the first minute hasn't been worked until StartDate + 1 minute
2. Your working day ends at 10 but your logic includes any time where the hour portion <= 10, so it is incrementing minutesWorked up to 10:59:59. I think the logic should be just less than not less than or equals: ... && current.getHours() < workHoursEnd

Comment: You are right @nickW as Nat Taylor mentioned above, the JavaScript does not calculate as I expected.